# Accessing a text box on a worksheet multipage object (Not a VBA userform)

Tags: excel, vba, object, multipage

I've created a multipage object in a worksheet object. Works beautifully. But I want to access a text box that is on the second page of the multipage object. I've spent hours searching and can't find a solution. I thought it'd be something like:

```
With Sheet6.InputArea
    With .Pages("Details")
        With .texbox4.value = "100"

        End With
    End With
End With
```

Would be hugely grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

`With` requires an object reference, but the expression `.texbox4.value = "100"` will evaluate to a boolean type

```
.texbox4.value = "100"
```

should work fine without the `With...End with`

Answer (score 0):

I've opened the developer tab and recorded a macro to see the output. I tweaked the code a bit and produced the following:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 1")).TextFrame2. _
TextRange.Characters.Text = "Goodbye moon..."
```

The original result from the macro recorder was:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 1")).Select
Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Hello World!!!"
```

I chose to replace `ActiveSheet` with a particular name and wanted to reference directly without requiring a selection.

Hopefully using the Macro record function may help you to find the items reference you're looking for.